# How to align numbers to right in excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have written a program in Python. using pandas that creates an excel file which shows numbers and strings in a few sheets. I want the numbers to be aligned to the right.
Right now it looks like this:

```
Test name   Failed\passed  Running time
Test A      Passed                    3
```

How can i move the number column to the right? 
I tried using this:

```
df1.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'right'})
```

But it did not fix the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ this one: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Maybe this one will work for you

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'align': 'right','bold': True, 'bottom':6})
```

and then maybe pass it to conditional_format